# When do deletes get applied in Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I was reading about Lucene and I'm confused as to when deletes (term or query) are applied to segments? Is it when a segment is flushed (by a DWPT) or at index commit (across all segments)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they happen on a segment level, separate to other segments in the same shard and/or index, and the deletes themselves are applied at merge time

merging happens automatically - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/index-modules-merge.html